# ASP.NET Core - JwtBearer 2.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt

I'm trying to implement JWT in ASP.NET Core Web API. In version 1.1.2 of JwtBearer I have this code in my Startup.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     ...

     services.Configure<JwtSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("jwt"));

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     ...
     var jwtSettings = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<JwtSettings>();
     app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
     {
          AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
          TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
          {
               ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.Issuer; // "http://localhost:5000"
               ValidateAudience = false,
               IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Key)) // some secret Key
          }
     });

     app.UseMvc();
}
```

How this code should looks in JwtBearer 2.0.0?

I installed this package like this:

> dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer

My .NET Core Version:

> 2.0.0

Comment: Here you can find an example project with 2.1.0 [AspNetCore.JwtBearer.VueJS](https://github.com/tinohager/AspNetCore.JwtBearer.VueJS)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the above code to transition this to dotnet core 2.0 you need to refactor as below... well adjust it as per your requirements, this is a quick answer while in transit.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(o => {
            o.Audience = Configuration.GetSection("jwt:Audience").Value;
            o.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("jwt:Authority").Value;
            o.RequireHttpsMetadata = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("jwt:RequireHttps");
            o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
            {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
                {
                    c.NoResult();
                    c.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    return c.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid Token");
                }
            };
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // ...
        app.UseAuthentication();
        // ...
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work for you:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

{

```
      services.Configure<JwtSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("jwt"));

      var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();     

      var jwtSettings = provider.GetService<JwtSettings>();


        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {                                   
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {                        
                    ValidateIssuer = jwtSettings.Issuer;
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Key)) // some secret Key

                };                   

            });




}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
 ....

  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseMvc();

}
```